# Keep first and drop the next duplicate rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, duplicates

I want to keep the first row from the set of duplicates. I am also trying to append the current input file. My doubt is if both deleting the duplication and appending the same file, will it be possible? If so then the code below referring the Pandas doc isnt working.

Input:

```
,id_merged,time_1,time_2,gps_1or3,gps_2or4
0,00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006 #duplicate_keep
1,00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006 #duplicate_remove
2,00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006 #duplicate_remove
3,00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006 #duplicate_remove
4,00022d9064bc,1073260803,1073260810,819213,439954
5,00904b4557d3,1073260803,1073261920,817526,439458
6,00022de73863,1073260804,1073265410,817558,439525
7,00904b14b494,1073260804,1073262625,817558,439525 
8,00904b14b494,1073260804,1073265163,817558,439525 
9,00904b14b494,1073260804,1073263786,817558,439525
10,00022d1406df,1073260807,1073260809,820428,438735
0,00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
1,00022dba8f51,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
2,00022de1c6c1,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
3,003065f30f37,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
4,00904b48a3b6,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
5,00904b83a0ea,1073260803,1073260810,819213,439954
6,00904b85d3cf,1073260803,1073261920,817526,439458
7,00904b14b494,1073260804,1073265410,817558,439525
8,00904b99499c,1073260804,1073262625,817558,439525
9,00904bb96e83,1073260804,1073265163,817558,439525
10,00904bf91b75,1073260804,1073263786,817558,439525
```

Expected Output: Index=None, Header=None

```
00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
00022d9064bc,1073260803,1073260810,819213,439954
00904b4557d3,1073260803,1073261920,817526,439458
00022de73863,1073260804,1073265410,817558,439525
00904b14b494,1073260804,1073262625,817558,439525
00022d1406df,1073260807,1073260809,820428,438735
00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
00022dba8f51,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
00022de1c6c1,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
003065f30f37,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
00904b48a3b6,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
00904b83a0ea,1073260803,1073260810,819213,439954
00904b85d3cf,1073260803,1073261920,817526,439458
00904b14b494,1073260804,1073265410,817558,439525
00904b99499c,1073260804,1073262625,817558,439525
00904bb96e83,1073260804,1073265163,817558,439525
00904bf91b75,1073260804,1073263786,817558,439525
```

Match every element of the row and if entire row is duplicate then keep the first and delete the rest of the duplicates.

Code:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('input.csv'), index_col=[0], header=[' ','id_merged','time_1','time_2','gps_1or3','gps_2or4'])


df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')

df.to_csv('dart_small_final.csv',mode = 'a',header=False, index=False)
```

**Edit One:**

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('dart_small_final.csv', index_col=[0], header=[' ','id_merged','time_1','time_2','gps_1or3','gps_2or4'])


df.drop_duplicates(keep=first, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df.to_csv('dart_final.csv', header=None, index=None)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "remove_dup.py", line 4, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('dart_small_final.csv', index_col=[0], header=[' ','id_merged','time_1','time_2','gps_1or3','gps_2or4'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 562, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 315, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 645, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 799, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1213, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 504, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:4950)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add parameter `inplace=True`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u""",id_merged,time_1,time_2,gps_1or3,gps_2or4
0,00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
1,00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
2,00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
3,00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
4,00022d9064bc,1073260803,1073260810,819213,439954
5,00904b4557d3,1073260803,1073261920,817526,439458
6,00022de73863,1073260804,1073265410,817558,439525
7,00904b14b494,1073260804,1073262625,817558,439525
8,00904b14b494,1073260804,1073265163,817558,439525
9,00904b14b494,1073260804,1073263786,817558,439525
10,00022d1406df,1073260807,1073260809,820428,438735
0,00022d9064bc,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
1,00022dba8f51,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
2,00022de1c6c1,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
3,003065f30f37,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
4,00904b48a3b6,1073260801,1073260803,819251,440006
5,00904b83a0ea,1073260803,1073260810,819213,439954
6,00904b85d3cf,1073260803,1073261920,817526,439458
7,00904b14b494,1073260804,1073265410,817558,439525
8,00904b99499c,1073260804,1073262625,817558,439525
9,00904bb96e83,1073260804,1073265163,817558,439525
10,00904bf91b75,1073260804,1073263786,817558,439525"""
```

```
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), index_col=0)
print (df)
       id_merged      time_1      time_2  gps_1or3  gps_2or4
0   00022d9064bc  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
1   00022d9064bc  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
2   00022d9064bc  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
3   00022d9064bc  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
4   00022d9064bc  1073260803  1073260810    819213    439954
5   00904b4557d3  1073260803  1073261920    817526    439458
6   00022de73863  1073260804  1073265410    817558    439525
7   00904b14b494  1073260804  1073262625    817558    439525
8   00904b14b494  1073260804  1073265163    817558    439525
9   00904b14b494  1073260804  1073263786    817558    439525
10  00022d1406df  1073260807  1073260809    820428    438735
0   00022d9064bc  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
1   00022dba8f51  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
2   00022de1c6c1  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
3   003065f30f37  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
4   00904b48a3b6  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
5   00904b83a0ea  1073260803  1073260810    819213    439954
6   00904b85d3cf  1073260803  1073261920    817526    439458
7   00904b14b494  1073260804  1073265410    817558    439525
8   00904b99499c  1073260804  1073262625    817558    439525
9   00904bb96e83  1073260804  1073265163    817558    439525
10  00904bf91b75  1073260804  1073263786    817558    439525
```

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
#or assign output to df
#df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print (df)
       id_merged      time_1      time_2  gps_1or3  gps_2or4
0   00022d9064bc  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
1   00022d9064bc  1073260803  1073260810    819213    439954
2   00904b4557d3  1073260803  1073261920    817526    439458
3   00022de73863  1073260804  1073265410    817558    439525
4   00904b14b494  1073260804  1073262625    817558    439525
5   00904b14b494  1073260804  1073265163    817558    439525
6   00904b14b494  1073260804  1073263786    817558    439525
7   00022d1406df  1073260807  1073260809    820428    438735
8   00022dba8f51  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
9   00022de1c6c1  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
10  003065f30f37  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
11  00904b48a3b6  1073260801  1073260803    819251    440006
12  00904b83a0ea  1073260803  1073260810    819213    439954
13  00904b85d3cf  1073260803  1073261920    817526    439458
14  00904b14b494  1073260804  1073265410    817558    439525
15  00904b99499c  1073260804  1073262625    817558    439525
16  00904bb96e83  1073260804  1073265163    817558    439525
17  00904bf91b75  1073260804  1073263786    817558    439525
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did make the changes as you mentioned but I am getting error. Made a Edit section.

Comment: I think if `csv` has header, use `df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', index_col=0)`, if not add parameter `names` - `df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', index_col=0, names=[' ','id_merged','time_1','time_2','gps_1or3','gps_2or4'])`.

Comment: It has header and Index both as shown in the input section.

Comment: Could use some guidance with this one too .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039842/scrape-user-location-from-twitter Thanks in Advance